# How to write methods without so many "this."?

Tags: javascript

Are there ways to avoid using `this.` before each member in the method body?

JavaScript is amazing in many ways, but one thing that makes it hard to read is that you must use `this.` before every member:

```
TList.on_key = function(key) {
    if (key == 116) {
        this.sid++;
        if (this.sid > this.items.length - 1) this.sid = this.items.length - 1
        if (this.sid >= this.d + (this.h * this.columns)) this.d++
    }
```

Would be much easier to read without all those `this.` :

```
TList.on_key = function(key) {
    if (key == 116) {
        sid++;
        if (sid > items.length - 1) sid = items.length - 1
        if (sid >= d + (h * columns)) d++
    }
```

Comment: If you're rather prefer to write less code, you might consider looking into LiveScript or CoffeeScript which both have a shortcut for `this.` which is simply a `@` so `this.foo` becomes `@foo`. As long as we're writing javascript, we'll have to live with this...

Comment: excellent question. one of the most mature and expert level questions i have seen. appreciate it buddy.

Answer (score 3):

Yes you can by using the "controversial" [`with` statement](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/with) as long as you're not in "strict mode", where it's prohibited.

```
TList.on_key = function(key) {
    with(this) {
        if (key == 116) {
            sid++;
            if (sid > items.length - 1) sid = items.length - 1
            if (sid >= d + (h * columns)) d++
        }
    }
}
```

Be sure to fully learn about it before using it though, as its semantics can catch people off guard.

Comment: it's horrible for optimization, but this definitely deserves to be on the answer list

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately not. Javascript don't have a scope control like Java. You need specify if want get a local var or a object var "this". But you can name it.

```
var Test = function(){
   var $ = this;
   $.test = function(){
      return 'lalalal';
   };
};
```

Comment: I would avoid using `$` - Might lead to confusion with JQuery

Comment: This is a simple example :)

He can use any variable to use as "this".

Answer (score 0):

"this" parameter is very important in object oriented programming, and its value is determined by the invocation pattern in JavaScript that is why we can not avoid this.
for more information you can read Function Invocation in "JavaScript: The Good Parts" by Douglas Crockford.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately that's not possible. And I would recommend not using the `with statement` as it has its drawbacks. Please test your code using [The JavaScript Code Quality Tool](http://www.jslint.com/)

The JavaScript this keyword is used within any function scope or the global scope, and in each scope it receives a different value. The value of this inside a function, effectively depends on the object which called it. Read more on [this keyword](http://www.devign.me/javascript-this-keyword)